# Thanking God for things

Tags: tefilla, theology

Considering that we do not know God's ultimate plan, and we know that things that seem good now can actually turn out to be for the better down the road, we must also assume that things that seem good now can also turn out to be bad down the road. Thus, how can we thank God for anything good that happens to us if it could really be a mixed blessing, or even a curse in disguise?

Comment: Is this a rhetorical question or are you looking for an answer?

Comment: @Daniel Yes, I want to know why/how we are able to thank God for things if it's possible that they are actually bad for us...

Comment: Isn't it fair to say that if God is benevolent, then everything that he does is for our good? Or at least that it is for the general good?

Comment: @Daniel I suppose, but I am having more of a difficulty in understanding why/how we are thanking God for potential punishment. Or, perhaps, I should be asking why we delineate at all between good and bad when thanking God if ultimately we do not know which is truly which.

Comment: Your question assumes we actually thank God for the seemingly good, but not for the bad. Can you demonstrate that? I ask because when it comes to blessings, there is the rule that one must bless God over the bad as one does over the good ([Mishnah Berakhot 9:5](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/משנה_ברכות_ט_ה)). That is why we say _Barukh Dayan ha-Emet_ over bad tidings (see [Mishneh Torah - Hilkhot Berakhot 10:3](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/2510.htm#3) onwards).

Comment: Adding on to what Tamir said, there is a common custom to respond "Baruch HaShem" when someone asks how you are, even if you are not well.

Comment: This concept is discussed in the Talmud (don't recall where) regarding why G-d saved Yishma'el. When Hagar and Yishma'el where in the desert and thirsty, Yishma'el cried. The angel says to Hagar that God heard the voice of the child "as he is". The Talmud explains that the angels said that Yishma'el should not be saved because of what he would eventually become. God's answer to that was that he is being saved becaused he prayed for help, now, and God considers the immediate actions; not always the future ones.

Comment: @DanF if you can source that (I don't remember where it is either), that'd make the basis of a good answer.

Comment: @MonicaCellio [Chabad.org's English translation of Rashi on Bereshit 21:17](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8216/jewish/Chapter-21.htm#showrashi=true&v=17) gives Rosh Hashanah 16b and Gen. Rabbah 53:14, although to be honest, I'm not sure of it's relevance, as it deals with judging people for their intent and actions, whereas we're talking here about thanking God for his part in shaping the resulting events.

Comment: @TamirEvan (from 2 comments ago) - Isn't the question based off of exactly that distinction?  We thank G-d one way for good and one way for bad - how do we know which is really which?

Comment: The basis of my mentioning the verse from Genesis 21:17 is to expand on a principle. We are supposed to emulate G-d's qualities. Just as G-d judges people as they currently act, we should also judge G-d's actions toward us as for its current result, not based on what COULD happen later.

Comment: @DanF (1) "... _we should also judge G-d's actions toward us as for its current result_" - Do you mean to say that if God afflicts us, we are to judge His actions (and - by extension - Him) to be bad, at that given time??? Besides the _Chilul ha-Shem_ I see in it, it flies in the face of what I brought in my first comment (and Yoni in his answer). (2) "_We are supposed to emulate G-d's qualities_ ..." - Can you source or demonstrate your claim that our obligation to emulate God extends to how we act towards Him?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. All that God does is for the Good (Berachos 60b)
2. Brachos are dependent on what has occurred to the one making the bracha now (Berachos 60a השתא מיהא טובה הוא and לדידיה). They are *personal* and *timely* expressions to God.

Thus, for bad events we should also be thanking God, but since brachos look at what just happened we instead make the bracha "dayan HaEmes". Nevertheless, it should be said with joy since "al is for the good". (Rambam Hil Berachos 10;3 from Berachpos, ibid)

Also see [Rabbi Sacks](http://www.rabbisacks.org/faith-lectures-judaism-justice-and-tragedy-confronting-the-problem-of-evil/) has an interesting lecture on this topic and differentiates between the perspective of Halacha and Agaddah.

Answer (score 0):

Though not to detract from @Yoni's answer, which was great and authoritative, I would like to offer a perspective that is more general in principle. Man needs to praise and bless the Creator, always, because He is the Creator and we are not. At the same point, blessing the Creator effects a change in man as well; it changes our consciousness to a sort of awareness of the divine. It is true that all the Creator wills is for the good, so we can rest assured that even though we might attach a blessing to something particular, we are also blessing Him for His greatness. This way, when something goes wrong, we have the proper consciousness to understand that the Blessed One is behind everything and has our best in mind for the outcome.